# terraform - github_branch_protection: use username instead of node_id

Tags: github, terraform, terraform-provider-github

I'm using GitHub Terraform provider with the resource `github_branch_protection` (documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/branch_protection )

I'm using the argument `required_pull_request_reviews.pull_request_bypassers` (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/branch_protection#pull_request_bypassers)

The documentation says:

```
pull_request_bypassers: (Optional) The list of actor Names/IDs that are allowed to bypass pull request requirements. Actor names must either begin with a "/" for users or the organization name followed by a "/" for teams.
```

So according to it I should be able to use username. It's confirmed by the example also:

```
required_pull_request_reviews {
    dismiss_stale_reviews  = true
    restrict_dismissals    = true
    dismissal_restrictions = [
      data.github_user.example.node_id,
      github_team.example.node_id,
      "/exampleuser",
      "exampleorganization/exampleteam",
    ]
  }
```

(ok this example is using `dismissal_restrictions` but the documentation is the same about the use of actor Names/IDs)

The problem is that when I use `/username` I have the following error:

```
│ Error: Could not resolve to a node with the global id of '/username'
```

My terraform plan contains:

```
required_pull_request_reviews {
          ~ pull_request_bypassers          = [
              + "/username",
            ]
        }
```

Do you know what am I making wrong and how to use `username` instead of `node_id`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a data source to get the `node_id` of the user you're trying to add and reference the result in the `dismissal_restrictions`, similar to `data.github_user.example.node_id`?

Comment: Yes. But for technical reasons, it's much more complicated to get `node_id` using data_source. I took the `username` from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/data-sources/organization_teams which has a `members` field but it's a string

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by stating that it’s more complicated. You can have a variable that’s named username and then reference that variable in the data source to retrieve the node_id of the user.

Comment: This looks to be related to [issue 908](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/908) on the provider but for me, it has been fixed in version 5.18.0

Answer (score 0):

I also could not get `username` working, but I followed the advice [here](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/908#issuecomment-1440450648) and used `node_id` successfully. Perhaps that is an ok workaround for you.

Here is an example adding an app:

```
data "github_app" "example" {
  slug = "my-application-slug"
}

...

required_pull_request_reviews {
  pull_request_bypassers = [
    data.github_app.example.node_id
  ]
}
```